# Trying to compile aseprite but fails

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to compile aseprite but I keep getting this error (it usually compiles successfully on ubuntu unity)
[image: Here is the Error in question]

I don't know what I have to do now to fix it, thanks in advance for your help
PS: I'm using ubuntu 23.04

Comment: You might want to start by taking those compile errors back to the developer.  "Undefined reference to [symbol]" usually means that there's either missing dependencies or the code is not up to date with the GCC versioning or such because things *do* change in GCC and other libraries that make older code invalid.